# Inline text box relative to other box

Tags: css, text, inline

I had huge problem because i don't have any idea. I need to create inline texts relative to next box. Like on the attached picture:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6yt0.png).
 - texts should be inline
 - and when the box will too small box with image with texts should break to next line like when we use `flex-wrap`

Comment: We can't help without your code

Comment: but i don't have a code i need idea to do it :D 
I show it on the picture :D

Comment: You need to have a parent object like `div` and text and box as child, after that, use `text-align: center;` to center the elements.